# Getting instances from a list of types

Tags: c#, linq, types

I have the following code, but I cannot make it to run. 
All I want to create a list of instances from a given list of types.

```
List<Type> types = new List<Type>
{
    typeof(String),
    typeof(Double),
    typeof(Object)
};

List<object> instances = types.Select(t => Activator.CreateInstance(t) as t);
```

I get the error

```
> t is a variable but is used like a type
```

Comment: Could you exaplin "*i cannot make it run*" further?

Comment: I edited the question with the syntax error I am getting.

Comment: Well this won't even compile as you're attempting to cast it to the actual type you can say List<object> instances = types.Select(t => Activator.CreateInstance(t)).ToList(); but this still will break at runtime as not all of these have default constructors

Comment: The error is that you cant cast because you do not know what type it is, remove `as t` because 1. you cant cast to an instance only to a type and 2. you do not know what the type is. Also you need to add `.ToList()` because you cant implicitly convert an IEnumerable<T> to List<T> instance, you have to create it.

Comment: Does `typeof(t)` work there?

Answer (score 2):

The compile error here is due to the fact that by saying *as t* you're not allowing the compiler to auto cast it to type object. This code is still buggy as it requires that all types in the list have default constructors (string does not have a default constructor).

Comment: The code in your comment works, and the types in my code are meant as examples. I plan to create a `List<BaseClass>` and use derived types to create polymorphic instances.

Comment: Don't know exactly what the purpose here is but the one time I wrote code like this it turned out to be insanely smelly code.

Comment: I have some possible calculations I want my application to perform. For every `Selection` instance I create, I need the calculations, so I have a class for each type of calculation. I want to create, at application startup  via IoC or dynamic dll loading, a list of all the possible calculations I could instantiate. So if I have a base class `Calculation` and subclasses `MaxCalculation`, `AverageCalculation`, etc. And for every `Selection` I create, I need one instance of each available subclass of `Calculation`. And I totally agree my code smells the way it is now.

Comment: I created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752529/how-to-create-one-instance-of-each-subclass-of-a-base-class